# Rails add column converts into create table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using rails 2.3.8
I want to add a column locked to citizen table using the following command

```
ruby script/generate migration AddLockedToCitizens locked:boolean
```

and the generated code after adding the default value is:

```
class AddLockedToCitizens < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :citizens, :locked, :boolean, :default => false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :citizens, :locked
  end
end
```

and the error message is:

```
==  CreateCitizens: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:citizens)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "citizens" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "citizens" ("id" serial primary key, "palID" character varying(255), "name" character varying(255), "email" character varying(255), "phone" character varying(255), "bdate" date, "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

the error is creating the table instead of alter table and add the required column

Comment: The problem isn't the new migration. Did you mess with the original "CreateCitizens" migration?  Did you change its timestamp in the migration file name?

Comment: the table is created few weeks ago and there is a previous add column done successfully before this time, i cannot determine the cause of the problem

Comment: You have a migration called "CreateCitizens" ?  Did you or someone else change the file name? If the timestamp in the filename is now greater than the last-migrated point it will attempt to run "CreateCitizens" again.